# Building a .deb-file for Raspberry Pi

Tags: build, raspberry-pi, deb, dpkg

I'm trying to build a .deb-file for installation on a Raspberry Pi 4. I'm using Ubuntu on the computer which I use for building: 'uname -a':

```
Linux helm 6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 10:53:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Uname on the Pi gives:

```
Linux remote 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

When I try running the program, I get:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/b4rker: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I've been trying to build using dpkg, and I've set every parameter I know for armhf - the architecture of a Raspberry - and the installation on the Pi seem to work. I've also tried arm64.
I've tried to run the program using sudo, and that gave me something else: `/usr/bin/b4rker: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Any ideas?